# Haskell function that converts type to string by type application

Tags: string, haskell, types, converters

So, I'd like to have a function / value like this :

```
converter :: Converter a
```

where `Converter` would be some type family that always results in `String` and is used just so that we can apply the type that we want to convert to `String` by using type application e.g.

```
converter @Int => "Int"
```

I was thinking of using `Typeable` class which has `typeOf` function. Unfortunately that requires an actual value for it to work.

I could use `Proxy` to supply "actual" value, but than I'd have to remove `Proxy` from the resulting `String` and that feels a bit dirty and error prone.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could exploit a bunch of extensions: `AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables`, and produce a variant of @Cubic's answer.

```
> :{
| convert :: forall a . Typeable a => String
| convert = show . typeRep $ Proxy @ a
| :}
> convert @ Int
"Int"
> convert @ String
"[Char]"
> convert @ Float
"Float"
```

Comment: Do you maybe know a trick by which we can get type synonym in the form of a string (without template haskell)?

Comment: @Reygoch I'm not sure about that, sorry.

Comment: @Reygoch Type synonyms are reduced to their definition by the compiler; TH is the only hope to get their names at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Typeable

main = print $ typeRep (Proxy @Int)
```

`typeRep` is designed to take a proxy and will only concern itself with the type on that proxy (so no need to remove anything). Sure, the additional `Proxy` in there is not quite the syntax you're looking for but it's pretty much the same thing right?

Comment: I missed `typeRep` function :D, but still I want something with type signature of `converter :: Typeable => Convert a' that i can just call with simple type application.

Comment: @Reygoch I'm like 50% sure that's impossible with haskells type system.

Comment: @Reygoch If it wasn't, there would be no need to have things like `Proxy` around in the first place.

Comment: @Cubic Proxies can now be replaced with ambiguous types and explicit type applications. There is almost no reason to use them (IMO), except when dealing with old libraries which predate the new alternative.

Comment: @chi The only use I have ever encountered was: `data Some con = forall a. con a => Some (Proxy a)`. Without the `Proxy`, I don’t think a pattern match can bind the type "contained" in a `Some` to a name: `case _ :: Some Show of Some (Proxy :: Proxy introduced) -> _`

Comment: @HTNW Interesting, thanks. There's also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50160423/3234959) which apparently can't be done without proxies, but I consider that to be a GHC deficiency.

Comment: @HTNW Without the proxy, this compiles, though `foo :: (forall a. (Show a => b)) -> Some Show -> b ; foo f Some = f` and one can pass an argument like `bar :: forall a. Show a => Int ; bar = length (show (undefined :: a))` which has access to the existentially-quantified `a`. A bit cumbersome, but it seems feasible.